# How to Submit a Contact Form and Not Redirect to Another Page

Tags: php, forms, redirect, contacts

I can't find anyone asking a similar question - I built a simply contact form and when I click submit, it takes me to the page on which the php for sending the message is written. I was wondering how I could make this not happen and instead just display a "thank you" message underneath the submit button, or something similar.

I based my code off of this tutorial. http://www.freecontactform.com/html_form.php. The form sends an email fine, but I just don't want it to redirect to another page after submission.

```
    <form name="helpful-form" method="post" action="../helpful-form.php"> 
        <input type="radio" name="unhelpful" value="The Page Did Not Answer My Questions">Did Not Answer My Questions</input><br>
        <input type="radio" name="unhelpful" value="The Page Content Was Not What I Was Expecting"><br>
        <input type="radio" name="unhelpful" value="There Was Too Much Information On The Page"><br>
        <input type="radio" name="unhelpful" value="There Was Too Little Information On The Page"<br>
        <input type="radio" name="unhelpful" value="The Page Content Was Too Complicated"><br>
        <textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="recommendations"></textarea>
        <input type="text" name="email">Email: (optional) </input>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
      </form>
```

**helpful-form.php**

```
  <?php 

    $email_to = "*******************";
    $email_subject = "Website Recommendation/Question - Form Submission";

    function died($error) {
        echo ($error);
        die();
    }

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['unhelpful']) && !isset($_POST['recommendations'])) {
        died('Please Select A Reason Why This Page Is Unhelpful.');
    }

        $unhelpful = $_POST['unhelpful'];
        $recommendations = $_POST['recommendations'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

    $email_message = "A new website recommendation and/or question has been submitted from BestAttorney.com:\n";



    $email_message .= "This page was not helpful because: ".clean_string($unhelpful)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Other Comments from the User: ".clean_string($recommendations)."\n";
    $email_message .= "This Form Was Submitted by: ".clean_string($email)."\n";

    $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" . 
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

Thank you giving us your recommendations! We will respond to any questions you had in a timely manner. 

<?php die(); ?>
```

I am also aware that there is more I have to do to make sure that the form is more secure but for now I'd like to just get this fixed up. Any thoughts? Thanks guys!

Comment: Search for AJAX tutorials.

Comment: maybe search with keyword AJAX? It'll bring you to things like this: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form

Comment: Put everything inside the same file and set `action=""` or use Ajax as already stated.

Comment: You also have a syntax error in `<input type="radio" name="unhelpful" value="There Was Too Little Information On The Page"<br>` which should read as `<input type="radio" name="unhelpful" value="There Was Too Little Information On The Page"><br>` missing a `>`

Comment: Thanks for that tutorial link! I didn't know i needed AJAX but that tutorial looks like it has everything I need.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax: Example post with jquery

```
 $.post(url,data,function(data){alert('congratulations')});// I would go for showing a div that will fadeout with animation
```

or you can use you own php contact form with a special behavior, including this in your code

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) //or whatever $_POST related condition and if so
{
  //saving code or mailing code etc

    echo '<div class="specialMessage">Thank you! </div>';
 }?>
```

I personally like to do the latter but the difference is the reload

Ps: the url of the post method in your form should be the same page of the contact form for the latter. The redirect will take you to the same website

Comment: `$_POST.length` is not valid PHP, its JS if any, u wanted sthing like `!empty($_POST)`

Answer (score 0):

place the code in contact form..
and change the line to
  `<form name="helpful-form" method="post" action="">`

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I did this but it actually just reloaded the page. I'm assuming the only way to do this without re-loading the page is to do what other have said and use ajax. Thanks though!